# Is $f\in L^2$ the orthogonal sum of its conditional expectations?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, analysis

Let ($\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P$) be a complete probability space and suppose $$\mathscr{F}_1, \mathscr{F}_2,..., \mathscr{F}_k\subset \mathscr{F}$$

are independent, complete sigma algebras which, together, generate $\mathscr F$ up to completion.  Let $f\in L^2(\Omega,\mathscr{F}, \mathbb{R})$ have zero mean.   **Is it true that**

$$f=\sum_{i=1}^k E[f ~|~\mathscr{F}_i]$$ **and how to prove?**

I'm not sure if it matters but I'm particularly interested in the case where the $\mathscr F_i$ are the (completions of the) sigma algebras generated by independent Brownian motions $B_1,...,B_k$.

---

Maybe we can show $$\int_Ff=\int_F \sum_{i=1}^k E[f ~|~\mathscr{F}_i]$$ for every $F\in \mathscr{F}$?  If $F_j\in \mathscr{F}_j$ we have

$$\int_{F_j} \sum_{i=1}^k E[f ~|~\mathscr{F}_i]= \sum_{i=1}^k \int_{F_j} E[f ~|~\mathscr{F}_i]=\int_{F_j} f~~~+\sum_{i\neq j} \int_{F_j} E[f ~|~\mathscr{F}_i]=\int_{F_j} f~~~+\sum_{i\neq j} P(F_j) E[f ]=\int_{F_j}f$$
So that checks out.  But then if I try to integrate over $F=F_1\cap F_2\cap...\cap F_k$ for $F_i\in \mathscr{F}_i$ (looking toward a monotone class argument) I get (writing $F_i' := F_1\cap...\cap \hat F_i\cap...\cap F_k$),

$$ \sum_{i=1}^k \int_F E[f ~|~\mathscr{F}_i]= \sum_{i=1}^k \int_{F_i'} \mathbb{1}_{F_i}E[f ~|~\mathscr{F}_i] =\sum_{i=1}^k P({F_i'})\int \mathbb{1}_{F_i}E[f ~|~\mathscr{F}_i] = \sum_{i=1}^k P({F_i'})\int_{F_i}f  $$ which doesnt really look like $\int f$ to me.  But I guess I haven't used that the $\mathscr F_i$ generate $\mathscr F$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true.  Let $X_1, X_2$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = -1) = \frac 12$, and $f := X_1 \cdot X_2$.  Let $\mathcal F_i = \sigma(X_i)$ for $i=1,2$ and $\mathcal F = \sigma(X_1,X_2)$.  Then $\mathbb{E}[f | \mathcal F_i] = 0$ for $i=1,2$, but $f$ is not identically $0$ and in fact $\mathbb{P}(f = 0) = 0$.